# Java Loop won't work like I want

Tags: java

Sorry if this is simple question and it's my fault, but I can't figure out my own loop - it only works one time. At the moment, the loop builds all 20 cars at once, but I want to build only one car per click. Hope you understand me.

My loop code:

```
for (int j = 3;j <= 80; j+=4){
    if(CarsLv1.cars[j] == 0){
        for(int i=1;i <= 25;i+=2){
            Part.parts[i] -=1;
        }   
        //CarFrame.frames[1] -=1;                               
        CarsLv1.cars[j] +=1;

        switch(j){

            case 3:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Aston Martin DB9!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Aston_Martin_DB9Icon);
                break;}
            case 7:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Acura NSX!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Acura_NSXIcon);
                break;}
            case 11:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Ford Mustang!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Ford_MustangIcon);
                break;
            }
            case 15:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Moskvich 412!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Moskvich_412Icon);
                break;
            }
            case 19:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Kia Venga!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Kia_VengaIcon);
                break;
            }
            case 23:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Fiat 1500!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Fiat_1500Icon);
                break;
            }
            case 27:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Ferrari Enzo!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Ferrari_EnzoIcon);
                break;
            }
            case 31:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Aston Martin Rapide!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Aston_Martin_RapideIcon);
                break;
            }
            case 35:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Koenigsegg CCX!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Koenigsegg_CCXIcon);
                break;
            }
            case 39:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Honda Civic!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Honda_CivicIcon);
                break;
            }
            case 43:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Cadilliac ATS!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Cadilliac_ATSIcon);
                break;
            }
            case 47:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Mitsubishi Lancer Evolution X!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,ImagesHolder.Mitsubishi_LancerEvolutionXIcon);
                break;
            }
            case 51:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Infiniti FX!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Infiniti_FXIcon);
                break;
            }
            case 55:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Lancia Thema!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Lancia_ThemaIcon);
                break;
            }
            case 59:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Volvo XC90!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Volvo_XC90Icon);
                break;
            }
            case 63:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Acura CSX!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Acura_CSXIcon);
                break;
            }
            case 67:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Saab Sonett II!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Saab_SonettIIIcon);
                break;
            }
            case 71:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Renault Floride!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Renault_FlorideIcon);
                break;
            }
            case 75:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained BMW e34!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.BMW_e34Icon);
                break;
            }
            case 79:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained Chrysler Cordoba!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.Chrysler_CordobaIcon);                                   
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have collected all LVL 1 cars", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.MaxUpgradeIcon);
                break;
            }
            default:{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have collected all LVL 1 cars", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImagesHolder.MaxUpgradeIcon);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, loops won't work like you want. Use class property to remember the status.

Comment: @crelix What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: To mee this code is not getting external input at all. So where do you expect to get input *within* this loop? I just counts in steps of 4 from 3 to 80 and increments the relevant CarsLv1.cars[j] slot (preventing actions at alater time, but j never will have this value again.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a break after your `switch` statement. The `break`s in the `switch` statement only break the particular case, they don't exit the surrounding loop.

```
for (int j = 3;j <= 80; j+=4){
  if (CarsLv1.cars[j] == 0) {
    switch(j){
      case 3:
        // Whatever.
        break;  // This breaks the case.
    }
    break;  // This breaks the loop;
  }
}
```

---

Note, it would be a lot cleaner if you defined an enum representing the cars, something like:

```
enum Car {
  ASTON_MARTIN_DB9(3, "Aston Martin DB9", ImagesHolder.Aston_Martin_DB9Icon),
  ACURA_NSX(7, "Acura NSX", ImagesHolder.Acura_NSXIcon),
  // etc, for other cars.
  ;

  private final int number;
  private final String name;
  private final ImageIcon icon;

  private Car(int number, String name, ImageIcon icon) {
    // Assign parameters to fields.
  }

  // Add getters.
}
```

Then, instead of iterating through these numbers, you can iterate through the cars themselves:

```
boolean found = false;
for (Car car : Car.values()) {
  int j = car.getNumber();
  if(CarsLv1.cars[j] != 0) continue;

  for(int i=1;i <= 25;i+=2){
    Part.parts[i] -=1;
  }                                
  CarsLv1.cars[j] +=1;
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained " + car.getName() + "!", "Congratulations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, car.getIcon());
  found = true;
  break;
}
if (!found) {
  // Show the message about having collected all cars.
}
```

i.e. avoiding the need for this great big switch, and all the repeated code.

Answer (score 2):

> the loop builds all 20 cars at once, but I want to build only one car per click.

Hint: if you want the code to be only be executed once, and not multiple times in a row. Maybe you shouldn't use a loop.

Create a method "createCar" (or something similar) and call that method when you do your "click".